# Setting overflow: scroll or auto pushes div to top instead of staying put

Tags: html, css

I have an issue I can't figure out: the page in question is http://ndsmcobserver.com.

I have this in the sidebar:

```
<div class="photostream" style="max-height:150px">
    <h2 class="topic"><span class="title"><a href="link to photostream">Photostream</a></span></h2>
    // Flickr code here
</div> <!-- eo.photostream -->
```

When I set

```
.photostream { .overlay-x: scroll; }
```

The entire div, for some reason, moves all the way up the column and gets hidden by the advertisement. How do I get it to stay where it is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure with this overlay? isnt overflow-x?

Comment: You really don't expect us to scan your entire page for that code. Do ya?

Comment: No, I provided the relevant code - you can just "Control-F" for it. I provided the page so that it's easy to use Chrome's Inspector tool to see what CSS is affecting it.

And nope - I tried overflow-x and it just makes it completely disappear. You can kind of see the scrollbar hiding back there when using overflow-y.

Comment: No matches found when searching for photostream. We could help more if you jsfiddle it

Comment: AHH my mistake! I forgot it was cached for outside users so it was not showing up. Should be there now. I'm not really sure what's relevant to include in jsfiddle - unfortunately I didn't write it. I can try to see if I can reproduce in jsfiddle, but I can't really reproduce the Google AdSense loading I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It moves up because your ad is floated left and set as 80% width so it knows that it has some space left to fit beside it. The content inside photostream is `positioned absolute` so therefore you need to add the css `clear: both;` to your `.photostream` so that it has a dimension and acts like a container with things inside it.